# Custom Scroll Bars That Enable/Disable on Mouse Click

Tags: jquery

I've got a table of films. To keep each row reasonably short while including a synopsis and list of special features, I've created a ".synopsisSmall" div with a heigh of 20px. Inside that is either a ".synopsisFull" div or a ".Extras" div. ".synopsisSmall" expands to the size of its child when clicked. ".Extras" has a max-height of 200px, because some of the lists were just getting out of hand. I set its overflow to scroll, but then it became scrollable even collapsed, so I set its overflow to hidden and changed the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Tag all rows as collapsed
    $(".synopsisSmall").attr("isclicked", "notclicked");
})
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".synopsisSmall").click(function(){
    //Determine which row has been clicked on, and how tall its full contents is in each column
    var clickedID = $(this).attr("id");
    var synopsisHeight = $("#" + clickedID + ".synopsisFull").height();
    var featuresHeight = $("#" + clickedID + ".Extras").height();
    //Check if row is collapsed or expanded
    var currentHeight = $(this).attr("isclicked");
    //If collapsed, animate the row height to either the height of the synopsis or the height of the special features, whichever is greater
    if (currentHeight == "notclicked") {
        if (synopsisHeight > featuresHeight) {
            $("#" + clickedID + ".synopsisSmall").animate({"height":(synopsisHeight + "px")}, 500); }
            else {
            $("#" + clickedID + ".synopsisSmall").animate({"height":(featuresHeight + "px")}, 500); }
        //Make it scrollable
        $("#" + clickedID + ".Extras").css({"overflow":"auto"});
    //And tag it as expanded
    $("#" + clickedID + ".synopsisSmall").attr("isclicked", "clicked");
    //Collapse any expanded rows, and tag them as collapsed
    $(".synopsisSmall").not("#" + clickedID).animate({"height": "20px"});
    $(".synopsisSmall").not("#" + clickedID).attr("isclicked", "notclicked"); }
    //Otherwise, if the clicked row is already expanded, simply collapse it and disable scrolling
    else { $("#" + clickedID + ".synopsisSmall").animate({"height":"20px"});
    $("#" + clickedID + ".Extras").css({"overflow":"hidden"});
            //And then tag it as collapsed
            $("#" + clickedID + ".synopsisSmall").attr("isclicked", "notclicked"); }
})
});
```

Only problem is the scroll bars look ugly and take up a massive amount of horizontal space. So I did some Googling, and found a jQuery plugin called NiceScroll. Added the following below the line enabling scrolling:

```
$("#" + clickedID + ".Extras").niceScroll();
```

But now, when collapsed, it remains scrollable. And if re-expanded, NiceScroll's scroll bar sticks around, while the default scroll bar pops up behind it, looking ugly and taking up space.

Is there a way I can pull this off?

ETA: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/b9gy551w/) a JSFiddle link to what I had without NiceScroll. Not sure how to get the NiceScroll code in there, but basically when I try to use it the scroll bar doesn't disappear, and the content remains scrollable.

Comment: For better understanding, Please provide a **working demo** (*code snippet,jsfiddle ...*)

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: Okay, I've added a JSFiddle demo.

Comment: Well, you might start by tidying up your html - it's all over the place with stray tags which will not help you, and could be breaking things - hint: red in jsfiddle means it's wrong

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/b9gy551w/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove nicescroll use the below code:

```
  $("#" + clickedID + ".Extras").getNiceScroll().remove();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".synopsisSmall").attr("isclicked", "notclicked");
})
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".synopsisSmall").click(function() {
    var clickedID = $(this).attr("id");
    var synopsisHeight = $("#" + clickedID + ".synopsisFull").height();
    var featuresHeight = $("#" + clickedID + ".Extras").height();
    var currentHeight = $(this).attr("isclicked");
    if (currentHeight == "notclicked") {
      if (synopsisHeight > featuresHeight) {
        $("#" + clickedID + ".synopsisSmall").animate({
          "height": (synopsisHeight + "px")
        }, 500);
      } else {
        $("#" + clickedID + ".synopsisSmall").animate({
          "height": (featuresHeight + "px")
        }, 500);
      }
      $("#" + clickedID + ".Extras").css({
        "overflow": "auto"
      });
      $("#" + clickedID + ".synopsisSmall").attr("isclicked", "clicked");
      $(".Extras").not("#" + clickedID).css({
        "overflow": "hidden"
      });
      $(".synopsisSmall").not("#" + clickedID).animate({
        "height": "20px"
      });
      $(".synopsisSmall").not("#" + clickedID).attr("isclicked", "notclicked");
    } else {
      $("#" + clickedID + ".synopsisSmall").animate({
        "height": "20px"
      });
      $("#" + clickedID + ".Extras").css({
        "overflow": "hidden"
      });
      $("#" + clickedID + ".synopsisSmall").attr("isclicked", "notclicked");
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#" + clickedID + ".Extras").getNiceScroll().remove();
      $("#" + clickedID + ".Extras").niceScroll();
    }, 500);
  })
});
```

```css
.Extras {
  vertical-align: central;
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Extras li {
  line-height: 16px;
}

.Extras ul {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}

.synopsisSmall {
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: central;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
}

.synopsisFull {
  vertical-align: central;
  max-height: none;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

table,
td,
th {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  vertical-align: central;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  text-wrap: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
}

table {
  border: thin solid #FFF;
  background-color: #666;
}

td,
th {
  border: none;
  max-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.6.0/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
    
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Synopsis</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Special Features</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Batman Begins</td>
    <td>
      <div class="synopsisSmall" id="3">
        <div class="synopsisFull" id="3">After training with his mentor, Batman begins his war on crime to free the crime-ridden Gotham City from corruption that the Scarecrow and the League of Shadows have cast upon it.</div>
      </div>
      <td>2005</td>
      <td>
        <div class="synopsisSmall" id="3">
          <div class='Extras' id="3">
            <ul>
              <li><i>The Dark Knight</i> IMAX Prologue</li>
              <li>In-Movie Experience</li>
              <li>Additional Footage:
                <ul>
                  <li>Reflections on Writing</li>
                  <li>Digital Batman</li>
                  <li>BATMAN BEGINS Stunts</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>Behind The Story
                <ul>
                  <li>Tankman Begins</li>
                  <li>The Journey Begins</li>
                  <li>Shaping Mind and Body</li>
                  <li>GOTHAM CITY Rises</li>
                  <li>Cape and Cowl</li>
                  <li>Batman - The Tumbler</li>
                  <li>Path to Discovery</li>
                  <li>Saving Gotham City</li>
                  <li>Genesis of the Bat</li>
                  <li>Stills Gallery</li>
                  <li>Confidential Files</li>
          </div>
        </div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>The Bourne Supremacy</td>
    <td>
      <div class="synopsisSmall" id="7">
        <div class="synopsisFull" id="7">When Jason Bourne is framed for a CIA operation gone awry, he is forced to resume his former life as a trained assassin to survive.</div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>2004</td>
    <td>
      <div class="synopsisSmall" id="7">
        <div class='Extras' id="7">
          <ul>
            <li>Deleted Scenes</li>
            <li>Matching Identities: Casting</li>
            <li>Keeping it Real</li>
            <li>Blowing Things Up</li>
            <li>On the Move With Jason Bourne</li>
            <li>Bourne to be Wild: Fight Training</li>
            <li>Crash Cam: Racing Through the Streets of Moscow</li>
            <li>The Go-Mobile Revs Up the Action</li>
            <li>Anatomy of a Scene: The Explosive Bridge Chase Scene</li>
            <li>Scoring With John Powell</li>
            <li>The Bourne Mastermind (Part 2)</li>
            <li>The Bourne Diagnosis (Part 2)</li>
            <li>Audio Commentary With Director Paul Greengrass</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/b9gy551w/1/

Comment: Not sure what the setTimeout function is or how it works, and that JSFiddle is still having the same problem I was having with content remaining scrollable when collapsed, but I put the getNiceScroll().remove() code before each line changing overflow to hidden, and it works perfectly. Cheers!